# Angular 7 : Bootstrap 4 grid Image Display On ngIf

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a display grid using bootstrap 4's card.

I wish to loop through an array of images, but i want to only show the images of the correct status.

When I add the `*ngIf='image.status == sTab.status'` to my `<div class='card'>`

Yes, it does not show the card, but it leaves a blank space instead.

If I put the card inside it's own `<div *ngIf=''>` then it displays as a vertical list not a grid.

This is my **welcomeDisplay.component.html**:

```
<div class="container mainCard">
    <ngb-tabset justify='justified'>
        <div *ngFor='let sTab of statusTabs'>
            <ngb-tab>
                <ng-template ngbTabTitle><b>{{ sTab.title }}</b></ng-template>
                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-4" *ngFor='let image of welcomeDisplay; let i = index'>
                            <div class="card" *ngIf='image.status == sTab.status'>
                                <div class="card-title">
                                    <p>Index : {{ i }}</p>
                                    <small>Title : {{ image.title }}</small>
                                </div>                  
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <img src="{{imageURL}}{{image.imgSrc}}" 
                                         [alt]="image.originalname">                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>       
                    </div>
                </ng-template>
            </ngb-tab>
        </div>
    </ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="row" >
    <div  *ngFor='let image of welcomeDisplay; 
let i = index' [ngClass]="image.status !== sTab.status ? 'col-4':''">
       <div class="card" *ngIf='image.status == sTab.status'>
          <div class="card-title">
             <p>Index : {{ i }}</p>
             <small>Title : {{ image.title }}</small>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
             <img src="{{imageURL}}{{image.imgSrc}}" 
                [alt]="image.originalname">                     
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I have removed div class="col-4" and added conditional class statement [ngClass]="image.status !== sTab.status ? 'col-4':''"

Hope this code helps u.